# Elasticsearch with Tire, how can I get global facets to take queries and other facets into account when reporting the count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire, faceted-search

The problem can best be shown with a working example to get an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Example on Newegg's faceted search page...

Here's a link to just internal hard drives:
http://www.newegg.com/All-Desktop-Hard-Drives/SubCategory/ID-14

Here's the same link but with the $25-$50 facet applied:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007603%204025&IsNodeId=1&name=%2425%20-%20%2450

Notice how when the $25-$50 checkbox was checked the other price check boxes didn't disappear and they still retain the correct count value. This leads me to believe they are using global facets.

You can now click the $50-$75 facet and you get this:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007603%204025%204026&IsNodeId=1&name=%2450%20-%20%2475

In this case it still shows the count for each price range on the left but you get the results of both facets shown.

If you do a search for let's say "Western":
http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007603%204025%204026&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&SrchInDesc=western&Page=1&PageSize=20

Now it's all filtered correctly by the search terms and facets. The counts are correct in the faceted navigation and so are the search results.

---

I'm trying to replicate that behavior and I almost have it working (maybe).

Here is my search method:

```
  def self.search(params = {}, items_per_page: 25, sort_by: :published_at, sort_direction: "desc")
    tire.search(page: (params[:page] || 1), per_page: items_per_page) do
      query do
        filtered do
          query { string params[:search] } if params[:search].present?

          terms = []
          terms << { term: { category_id: params[:category_id] } } if params[:category_id].present?
          terms << { term: { published: params[:published] } } if params[:published].present?
          terms << { range: { word_count: { gte: params[:word_count].to_i } } } if params[:word_count].present?

          filter :and, terms if not terms.empty?
        end
      end

      facet "categories" do
        terms :category_id
      end

      facet "word_count" do
        histogram :word_count, interval: 200
      end

      facet "visible" do
        terms :published
      end
    end
  end
```

With that setup it all works except for example, let's say I want to facet on 2 categories instead of 1. That's impossible with this setup because as soon as I check off category 1 then the checkbox for category 2, 3, and so on disappear.

This makes me think I need to use `global: true` in my facets but then the facet count is never correct, it won't take into account the search query results or the results of the other facets. How can I get the best of both worlds because it seems crippled/unusable otherwise.

If doing `global: true` isn't the answer here then what else can I do?

Comment: Your question is unclear. why aren't you using an array of category ids in a :terms filter (vs term) instead of just one category_id?

Comment: May I ask what's unclear about it? Is the newegg example not enough? I'm also using a term for category_id because the data I'm running the facets over (article) can only have 1 category.

They are "terms" in the facet because I allow the user to filter by more than 1 category by using an array of checkboxes.

Comment: Did you found answer to your question? It seems that this is a tricky thing to elastic to handle out of the box, and only possible way is to perform N+1 requests one for data and N for facets, each facet request should ask for facet data and do not contain selected checkbox in request. But it may become a trouble on heavy loaded projects :(